# Right to Left Languages Issue between two "/"

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

The URL below has two arabic words but they are in the wrong place, what practices are available to handle this issue?

```
example.com/محا/ظة
```

I added city name in `/cityname/` and kw at the end `/cityname/kw` but in languages written from Right to Left the kw jump in the middle: `/kw/cityname`

Comment: Perhaps you should just percent-encode the URL instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The browser probably has taken care of that and decoded it so it's human readable. How are you generating that URL?

Comment: If the browser has decoded the encoded url to that form, I doubt there is anything one can do.